# Using combn() in R to find all possible t-test relationships, how to access the variables compared?

Tags: r, dataframe, t-test, combn

So, I have a DataFrame with a large number of variables, and I want to cross-check each variable with each other variable with a t-test.

A sample of my data, called `trust_news`:

| row | mean | polity2 | web | rsf | civil_liberties | freedom_of_expression | vdem_gov_censorship_effort | vdem_self_censorship_effort | vdem_freedom_of_expression | ciri_freedom_of_speech_and_press | media_integrity | vdem_critical_press | vdem_media_perspective | vdem_media_bias | vdem_media_corruption | vdem_media_freedom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.68 | 8 | 87.2661 | 25.69 | 0.785599008 | 0.758906967 | 0.731895466 | 0.742219428 | 1 | 1 | 0.81449235 | 0.889046047 | 0.782079459 | 0.693825991 | 0.733503755 | 1 |
| 2 | 2.8 | 8 | 94.8967 | 22.23 | 0.810742702 | 0.832891911 | 0.8447733 | 0.831499528 | 1 | 1 | 0.88417386 | 0.868772592 | 0.881994928 | 0.835622928 | 0.828566864 | 1 |
| 3 | 3.22 | 10 | 89.7391 | 14.6 | 0.821268417 | 0.83327835 | 0.883343829 | 0.805721471 | 1 | 1 | 0.829951651 | 0.917491749 | 0.725950972 | 0.709774199 | 0.874261064 | 1 |
| 5 | 2.96 | 10 | 74.3872 | 24.98 | 0.813949794 | 0.781986225 | 0.844615869 | 0.729330399 | 0.666666667 | 0.5 | 0.878769429 | 0.872387239 | 0.919019442 | 0.841939049 | 0.810193322 | 0.5 |

Then, I run this code on it:

```
trust_news_combos <- combn(trust_news, 1, t.test, simplify = TRUE)
```

First off, is the code correct? I have no clue what to put for `m` in the `combn()` function. AAnyway, that line gives me this:

|  | V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 | V5 | V6 | V7 | V8 | V9 | V10 | V11 | V12 | V13 | V14 | V15 | V16 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | c(t = 85.1670166474227) | c(t = 15.9614095646055) | c(t = 29.2365516170159) | c(t = 11.0778062107689) | c(t = 30.4673329981756) | c(t = 26.8521522144486) | c(t = 23.160185720972) | c(t = 25.1063414199952) | c(t = 17.1830959329723) | c(t = 11.06502519693) | c(t = 33.0841916129404) | c(t = 29.3707961673045) | c(t = 31.2455551028106) | c(t = 39.1490231250879) | c(t = 27.6089179039943) | c(t = 14.0719508946058) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | c(df = 32) | c(df = 32) | c(df = 32) | c(df = 32) | c(df = 32) | c(df = 32) | c(df = 32) | c(df = 32) | c(df = 32) | c(df = 32) | c(df = 32) | c(df = 32) | c(df = 32) | c(df = 32) | c(df = 32) | c(df = 32) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 2.69E-39 | 8.55E-17 | 1.18E-24 | 1.75E-12 | 3.29E-25 | 1.61E-23 | 1.46E-21 | 1.26E-22 | 1.03E-17 | 1.80E-12 | 2.55E-26 | 1.02E-24 | 1.51E-25 | 1.32E-28 | 6.88E-24 | 2.96E-15 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | c(3.00189912275063 | 3.14900996815846) | c(7.56066019283154 | 9.77267314050179) | c(73.5097801046279 | 84.5198259559781) | c(19.628297122971 | 28.4729149982411) | c(0.682586494865725 | 0.780396107679729) | c(0.639468676034051 | 0.744449016935646) | c(0.664192511270674 | 0.792289818305084) | c(0.665160025455844 | 0.782621785210823) | c(0.676674167771883 | 0.858679367682662) | c(0.543941635486123 | 0.78939169784721) | c(0.739756992152986 | 0.836824222392469) | c(0.730937293702635 | 0.839876930600395) | c(0.729509614919607 | 0.831257822777363) | c(0.709894349786553 | 0.787820841122538) | c(0.708427672557418 | 0.821287114048642) | c(0.647915673315896 | 0.867235841835619) |
| 5 | c(`mean of x` = 3.07545454545455) | c(`mean of x` = 8.66666666666667) | c(`mean of x` = 79.014803030303) | c(`mean of x` = 24.0506060606061) | c(`mean of x` = 0.731491301272727) | c(`mean of x` = 0.691958846484849) | c(`mean of x` = 0.728241164787879) | c(`mean of x` = 0.723890905333333) | c(`mean of x` = 0.767676767727273) | c(`mean of x` = 0.666666666666667) | c(`mean of x` = 0.788290607272727) | c(`mean of x` = 0.785407112151515) | c(`mean of x` = 0.780383718848485) | c(`mean of x` = 0.748857595454545) | c(`mean of x` = 0.76485739330303) | c(`mean of x` = 0.757575757575758) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | c(mean = 0) | c(mean = 0) | c(mean = 0) | c(mean = 0) | c(mean = 0) | c(mean = 0) | c(mean = 0) | c(mean = 0) | c(mean = 0) | c(mean = 0) | c(mean = 0) | c(mean = 0) | c(mean = 0) | c(mean = 0) | c(mean = 0) | c(mean = 0) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | 0.036110864 | 0.542976272 | 2.702603374 | 2.171062176 | 0.024009036 | 0.025769214 | 0.031443667 | 0.028832991 | 0.044676278 | 0.0602499 | 0.023826806 | 0.02674109 | 0.024975831 | 0.019128385 | 0.027703273 | 0.053835873 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | two.sided | two.sided | two.sided | two.sided | two.sided | two.sided | two.sided | two.sided | two.sided | two.sided | two.sided | two.sided | two.sided | two.sided | two.sided | two.sided |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | One Sample t-test | One Sample t-test | One Sample t-test | One Sample t-test | One Sample t-test | One Sample t-test | One Sample t-test | One Sample t-test | One Sample t-test | One Sample t-test | One Sample t-test | One Sample t-test | One Sample t-test | One Sample t-test | One Sample t-test | One Sample t-test |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10 | x[a] | x[a] | x[a] | x[a] | x[a] | x[a] | x[a] | x[a] | x[a] | x[a] | x[a] | x[a] | x[a] | x[a] | x[a] | x[a] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

It gives me the p-values I'm looking for in row 3, but how do I check which two columns are being checked?

Any help is appreciated and will be thanked in my final code!

Comment: I think you need `2` instead of `1`

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that after I posted. Point remains, how do I extract the two variables I was actually comparing in the t.test?

Comment: The output of `t.test` is a list structure.  What is your expected ouptut.  Do you want the output with only p.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a small function to compute exactly what you need, and use it instead of the standard function `t.test`.  For example:

```r
# get four column names
cols <- names(mtcars)[1:4]   # use trust_news instead of mtcars, and keep all the names

# compute the pval for a pair of names
pval <- function(pair) {
  value <- t.test(mtcars[, pair[1]], mtcars[, pair[2]])$p.value
  names(value) <- paste(pair, collapse = " vs. ")
  value
}

# do it for all pairs.  Don't simplify, and it will keep the names
combn(cols, 2, pval, simplify = FALSE)
#> [[1]]
#>  mpg vs. cyl 
#> 9.507708e-15 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> mpg vs. disp 
#> 7.978234e-11 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   mpg vs. hp 
#> 1.030354e-11 
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> cyl vs. disp 
#> 1.774454e-11 
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>   cyl vs. hp 
#> 8.321996e-13 
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> disp vs. hp 
#> 0.001545647
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to create a second `combn` on the column names

```
nm1 <-  combn(names(trust_news), 2, FUN = paste, collapse= '-', simplify = TRUE)
```

Then, we do

```
trust_news_combos <- combn(trust_news, 2, t.test, simplify = FALSE)
names(trust_new_combos) <- nm1
```

---

It may also better to get the output in a data.frame/tibble structure with `broom`  using `tidy` (run in `R 4.1.0`)

```
library(broom)
lst1 <- combn(trust_news, 2, \(y) t.test(y[1], y[2]) |>
                             tidy(), simplify = FALSE) |>
         setNames(nm1)

out <- Map(cbind, comparison = names(lst1), lst1) |>
       {\(x) do.call(rbind, x)}()
row.names(out) <- NULL
```

-output

```
head(out)
                 comparison   estimate estimate1  estimate2   statistic      p.value parameter    conf.low
1                  row-mean  -0.165000      2.75  2.9150000  -0.1914478 0.8599889461  3.112075  -2.8527609
2               row-polity2  -6.250000      2.75  9.0000000  -6.0633906 0.0014638846  5.268737  -8.8595564
3                   row-web -83.822275      2.75 86.5722750 -18.8602012 0.0002049939  3.229641 -97.4140679
4                   row-rsf -19.125000      2.75 21.8750000  -7.1441517 0.0027953086  3.671029 -26.8277783
5       row-civil_liberties   1.942110      2.75  0.8078900   2.2742727 0.1074862571  3.000494  -0.7752796
6 row-freedom_of_expression   1.948234      2.75  0.8017659   2.2809921 0.1067532047  3.002873  -0.7684766
   conf.high                  method alternative
1   2.522761 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
2  -3.640444 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
3 -70.230482 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
4 -11.422222 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
5   4.659500 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
6   4.664945 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
```

#### data

```
trust_news <- structure(list(row = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L), mean = c(2.68, 2.8, 3.22, 
2.96), polity2 = c(8L, 8L, 10L, 10L), web = c(87.2661, 94.8967, 
89.7391, 74.3872), rsf = c(25.69, 22.23, 14.6, 24.98), civil_liberties = c(0.785599008, 
0.810742702, 0.821268417, 0.813949794), freedom_of_expression = c(0.758906967, 
0.832891911, 0.83327835, 0.781986225), vdem_gov_censorship_effort = c(0.731895466, 
0.8447733, 0.883343829, 0.844615869), vdem_self_censorship_effort = c(0.742219428, 
0.831499528, 0.805721471, 0.729330399), vdem_freedom_of_expression = c(1, 
1, 1, 0.666666667), ciri_freedom_of_speech_and_press = c(1, 1, 
1, 0.5), media_integrity = c(0.81449235, 0.88417386, 0.829951651, 
0.878769429), vdem_critical_press = c(0.889046047, 0.868772592, 
0.917491749, 0.872387239), vdem_media_perspective = c(0.782079459, 
0.881994928, 0.725950972, 0.919019442), vdem_media_bias = c(0.693825991, 
0.835622928, 0.709774199, 0.841939049), vdem_media_corruption = c(0.733503755, 
0.828566864, 0.874261064, 0.810193322), vdem_media_freedom = c(1, 
1, 1, 0.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: What do the `|>` do? When I copy the code you wrote (thank you!) it gives a bunch of unexpected characters/inputs for some of the lines.

Comment: @cigarette_daygreams It is new operators= in R 4.1.0 base R. It is similar to `%>%` in dplyr.  If your R version is old, it won't work

Comment: apologies for noise.